# visual studio indentation has been changed automatically?

Tags: visual-studio

I have a file from third party where the curly brackets were in the next line but today when i see, all the brackets are moved on the same line as function name.

i would like to revert back all at once, please help.

Thanks in advance,
Sagar

Answer (score 0):

In the Top Menu

Tools -> Options -> Text Editor -> C# -> Formatting -> New Lines

there you find New line options for braces

I guess thats what you´re looking for

Comment: yeah, but how can apply this to the existing file.

Comment: oh, press CTRL + K, CTRL + D that should reformat your current file